# Representing time periods in the UI and database

Tags: javascript, sql, ruby-on-rails

I've recently adopted a project with an `Employee` model that needs to contain the person's available hours as an attribute.

The existing form uses 168 checkboxes to represent each hour in the week, and stores the information as seven 24 bit binary strings in the database, each bit acting as a boolean true or false for its corresponding hour in that day.

I'd really like to transition to something a little more elegant and manageable, but I haven't been able to come up with any simple solutions that match the existing implementation's flexibility.

Storing time periods as start and end times can be just as tedious to input when there can be multiple per day, and would likely make querying for availability at a particular time more complicated.

Is there a best practice for dealing with this type of information, both in the user interface and the database structure?

Comment: PostgreSQL natively supports time intervals as a data type.

Comment: That's definitely good to know, but I'm not sure it really solves the problem. If I'm not mistaken, those intervals aren't tied to a specific start or end time, so they would have to be used as part of a more complex data structure to represent all of the required information. I guess what I'm really looking for is a clean, manageable way to input, store, and query 168 booleans. Or a better way to represent each hour in the week.

Comment: Well you could pair up an interval field with a date field, such that the date field would give the start time and the interval the duration. Don't know whether that'd be better or worse than just two date fields; it'd depend on the semantics and the queries you'd want to run.

Comment: Most of the queries will be just checking if a user is available at a given time for a given duration. That might get complicated with this kind of representation, since query start times won't necessarily match up with attribute start times. You'd have to search for a start time before the query time with a duration that extends past the query duration. You would also have to validate that no periods in the model are overlapping.

Comment: Time is a really nasty thing to model.

Comment: I'm beginning to think the easiest way to do it is going to end up being a big bitmask and a few sizeable helper methods to help parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would model the data in the database this way.

[image: Employee/Day/Hour Relationship]

There's a many to many relationship between the employees and hours for each day of the week.

On the UI side, you could use checkboxes for the days and multiselect list boxes to set the hours for the given day.

Comment: This looks like the most promising approach so far. I was initially hesitant to model days of the week and the numbers 0 through 23, but it really does allow a much simpler way to query for availability.

Comment: On second thought, is there an advantage to extracting hours and days to their own tables like this? Why can't you replace `hour_id` and `day_id` with an `hour` integer and a `day` string? With proper validation, they should never take on an unexpected value, and I don't think this would take any flexibility away from the approach.

Comment: I did this to model proper normalization.  If you ever needed to store additional descriptors about the hours and days, there would be room to store it.  For example, the DOW table could have an int representing the numeric day, a Short_Day with Mon, Tue, Wed etc and a Long_Day with Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc.  Hour can have the int hour, then a char with 12am, 1am etc or 12-1am, 1-2am etc.  This would aide your interface by providing a variety of descriptors for human readability.

Comment: On a side note, this article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/Times%2c+dates+and+temporal+data./72661/ was just published today regarding dealing with time data in a database.  Maybe not helpful in this instance but interesting none-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just make time period blocks?

```
Employee
  Availability
    7AM -> 12PM
      Monday
      Tuesday
      Wednesday
    1PM -> 4PM
      Monday
      Tuesday
    1PM -> 5PM
      Wednesday
```

Each user would have a list of time blocks that represent one or more hours throughout the day. Each time block could also represent one or more days of the week.  Depending on how complex the users availability is there could be very little data or a lot.

The UI would not really have to change if you didn't want to as you could just figure out what check boxes are checked and build out a time period block.  If there is a gap of one or more hours between times it would just become another time period.

Adding Shift UI :: http://imm.io/6vGk

Displaying Employee Shifts :: http://imm.io/6vGv

Comment: So in this case, there would be a separate table of availabilities that had `start hour`, `end hour`, `day`, and `user_id` columns? That might make the database a little easier to look at, but I'm not convinced it would make either input or queries easier.

Comment: Yeah that could work for the database.  As for queries it just depends on the kind you'll be needing to do, the more complex the query the harder anything will be.  The UI can be whatever you want really ... for example I'll add some images to my answer above as to what I did for adding/displaying shifts

Answer (score 0):

We store employee schedules and non available hours in two different tables. The search is building available hours and then excludes non available. Data structure for employee schedules is quite complicated since storing schedule for every day just made our search very very slow and tables large.